# error:static_cast undeclared->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was porting from cpp to Objective C.

Objective C:

```
[pPacket SetHeaderSequenceNumber:static_cast<char>(m_transmitSequenceNumber + ASCII_ZERO)];
```

cpp:

```
pPacket->SetHeaderSequenceNumber(static_cast <char>(m_transmitSequenceNumber + ASCII_ZERO));
```

error:static_cast undeclared.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147156/casting-comparison-between-objective-c-and-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

objective-c is a superset of c, not c++ so static_cast is not supported in it. You can just use c-style cast:

```
[pPacket SetHeaderSequenceNumber:(char)(m_transmitSequenceNumber + ASCII_ZERO)];
```

Answer (score 4):

Objective C is a superset of C not C++. static_cast is a C++ operator so Objective C cannot use this.

However there is Objective C++ which does understand C++. To use this rename your .m file to .mm and Xcode will compile this as Objective C++