# C++11 for xCode errors

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, cocos2d-iphone, std

I want to use std collections, for example `std::vector` in my xCode 4.5 project. Following the explanation here [no type named 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819886/no-type-named-shared-ptr-in-namespace-std) I changed my compiler options accordingly, but now when I come to build the project I get a bunch of errors such as `Type float cannot be narrowed to GLubyte (aka unsigned char) in initializer list`.

These errors are in a ccType.h, which is part of the Cocos2d library I'm using for my game.

I'm thinking the right thing to do *is not* to start debugging Cocos2d, but to change some of the compiler options.

How should I proceed?

Here is the code that causes the errors:

```
static inline ccColor4B ccc4BFromccc4F(ccColor4F c) {
    return (ccColor4B){c.r*255.f, c.g*255.f, c.b*255.f, c.a*255.f};
}
```

The error message is exactly as I brought it above.

Comment: Show us the code that is causing the error.

Comment: And also please the complete and unedited error messages. And also please mark out in the code where the errors are.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey I edited the question to add the code. The error message is exactly as I wrote in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast the type accordingly because C++11 disallow implicit conversion in initialisers lists, specifically in this case from `float` to `unsigned char`.

I guess this should be enough to solve the issue:

```
return (ccColor4B){static_cast<GLubyte>(c.r*255.f), static_cast<GLubyte>(c.g*255.f), static_cast<GLubyte>(c.b*255.f), static_cast<GLubyte>(c.a*255.f)};
```

Comment: Only in initializer lists, though

Comment: Thanks @Jack. This with the idea to do a C style cast (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031054/errorstatic-cast-undeclared-objective-c)removed these errors, but now when I go to build my project I get new ones. "'~b2Body' is a private member of b2Body" in #endif  // !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES) && !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_VARIADICS)
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void destroy(pointer __p) {__p->~_Tp();} and "Invalid operands in binary expression ('b2Body' and 'b2Body *')" in for (; __first != __last; ++__first).